# Cassandra Titan/JanusGraph atomicity

Tags: cassandra, titan, cassandra-2.1, janusgraph

We are planning to use combination of Cassandra and Titan/JanusGraph db as the backend for one of our projects. As part of that, I have the below requirement.

Record/Vertex A and Record/Vertex B should be written onto the backend in an atomic way, i.e., either both the records are written or neither of the records are written. Essentially, I need to have multi-row atomic writes. However, from documentation of both Titan and Cassandra as listed below, this is what I found.

**Titan DB**

Titan transactions are not necessarily ACID. They can be so configured on BerkleyDB, but they are not generally so on Cassandra or HBase, where the underlying storage system does not provide serializable isolation or multi-row atomic writes and the cost of simulating those properties would be substantial

**Cassandra 2.0**

In Cassandra, a write is atomic at the partition-level, meaning inserting or updating columns in a row is treated as one write operation.

**Cassandra 3.0**

In Cassandra, a write operation is atomic at the partition level, meaning the insertions or updates of two or more rows in the same partition are treated as one write operation.

**I have below questions.**

1) we use titan DB with Cassandra 2.1.X. If I want to achieve multi-row atomicity how do I do that? Is there any solution to achieve this?

2) I see that Cassandra batch operation provides atomicity for multiple operations? But I don't see a corresponding operation in Titan DB to use this functionality. Am I missing some thing here or is there any way to use this?

3) As the Cassandra is heavily used in various applications and I am pretty sure  people have uses cases which requires multi-row atomic operations. How do people solve this?

4) I see that Cassandra 3.0 has this support. So when JanusGraph started supporting Casandra 3.0 (currently it only supports 2.1.x), should I expect this support in JanusGraph?